# DRBD no output of cat /proc/drbd

Tags: drbd

I sync my new disk, output of `drbdtop`:

```
Resource: myres: (Overall danger score: 14)
Local Disc(Primary):
volume 0 (/dev/drbd0): UpToDate(normal disk state)
volume 1 (/dev/drbd1): UpToDate(normal disk state)
volume 2 (/dev/drbd2): Inconsistent(data is not accessible or usable until resync is complete)

Connection to zfs.user.osdc2(Secondary): Connected(connected to zfs.user.osdc2)
volume 0: 
UpToDate(normal disk state)
volume 1:
UpToDate(normal disk state)
volume 2:
Replication:SyncTarget(local volume is being synchronized with data from zfs.user.osdc2) 95.6% remaining   UpToDate(normal disk state)
```

But there is no output in `cat /proc/drbd` about my resource. Only:

```
version: 9.0.9-1 (api:2/proto:86-112)
GIT-hash: f7b979e7af01813e031aac579140237640c94569 build by mockbuild@, 2017-09-14 17:45:45
Transports (api:16): tcp (9.0.9-1)
```

Why there is no output? How should I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The /proc/drbd file has been dropped in the DRBD 9.x releases. You should instead use `drbdadm status` to get the current state of the DRBD resources.

If you really insist on the old /proc/drbd output you can find this within the sysfs now. Note that this is per connection only. It is located at:

```
/sys/kernel/debug/drbd/resources/${resource_name}/connections/${hostname}/0/proc_drbd
```

Comment: [Here is the info about that from linbit](https://kb.linbit.com/detailed-drbd-resource-information)

Comment: The Linbit article is pretty useless. It only states the whereabouts in /sys but nothing about the nomenclature that changed for e.g. cs: where you have Off and Established which was not previously used.